# Double tap -> drag and drop stopped working in Chrome when using Logitech mouse

Tags: google-chrome, mouse, trackpad, magic-trackpad, ui

> OSX 10.9.4
>
> Chrome Canary: Version 38.0.2086.3 canary (64-bit)
>
> Chrome Stable: Version 35.0.1916.153

Trackpad, magic trackpad work as they should. In Chrome I can double tap on text and drag it and drop it from within the app, and out of the app.

However, when I use my logitech mouse, I can double tap, but I cannot drag and drop the text/image/whatever. If I switch to my trackpad I get the {+} icon and I can move the text around.

Any suggestions as to what I can do to fix this?

Comment: related [text-deselecting-when-using-logitech-mouse-scroll-wheel-in-sierra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/257298/text-deselecting-when-using-logitech-mouse-scroll-wheel-in-sierra/411688#comment582222_411688) and [trying-to-drag-drop-sometimes-is-reset-multiple-times-during-drag-with-mouse-logitech-m510](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/415537/trying-to-drag-drop-sometimes-is-reset-multiple-times-during-drag-with-mouse-l/415538#415538)

Answer (score 2):

I tested a few other mice, and it seems that it was my mouse that was causing the problem. The clicker got too much use over the last 5-6 years, and does not accept the click+hold any longer.

Comment: I've seen similar clicking issues and a [drag & drop issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/415537/trying-to-drag-drop-sometimes-is-reset-multiple-times-during-drag-with-mouse-l/415538#415538) with different Logitech M510 that were 3 and 4 years old. I also have seen reviews on Amazon mentioning the double click problem.