# Trying to drag & drop sometimes is reset multiple times during drag with mouse Logitech M510 on macOS

Tags: macos, bluetooth, mouse

Trying to drag & drop sometimes is reset multiple times during drag with mouse Logitech M510 on macOS Mojave and Catalina. This issue is new, I can reproduce it switching macs, usb receivers. Using a M705 mouse seems to work fine.

Report from Logitech Unifying software, using original Unifying Receiver dongle:

```
Logitech Unifying Software 1.3.375
Mac OS X 10.14.6 (18G8022)

Unifying Receiver @ 14100000
  Product ID: 0xc52b
  Firmware version: 12.10 (32)
  Location ID: 0x14100000
  Bus enumerator: -
  Hash: sanitized
  Devices: 2 (1 mice, 1 keyboards, 0 number pads)

  Mouse M510 @ 1
    Product ID: 0x4051
    Subclass: 0x2
    Bitfield: 0x4
    Serial Number: 0x4051sanitized
    Connection status: active
    Location ID: 0x0
    Receiver location ID: 0x14100000
...
```

Comment: related: [double-tap-drag-and-drop-stopped-working-in-chrome-when-using-logitech-mouse](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/138654/double-tap-drag-and-drop-stopped-working-in-chrome-when-using-logitech-mouse)

Comment: Having the same issue with a wired M500 on Catalina. Appears to be tied to the scroll wheel. When dragging over text, the scroll wheel sometimes moves slightly and the text deselects. Currently working around it by putting the scroll wheel in "click-to-click" mode so it doesn't move as easily.

Answer (score 2):

For my case, unfortunately the solution was replacing the 4-years-old Logitech M510 mouse! Looking at some Amazon reviews, this model frequently start to have issues after a few years.